# Send command from batch shell to shell

Tags: shell, batch-file, batch-processing

My structure looks like this:
I have one Windows PC which is running 24/7 in my cellar and I have one Windows PC in my office (at home). Both are in the same network and I have admin privileges on both.

How can I set up a batch-file on my office PC which can send a command to the other PC through the command line? I should be able to turn off and reconnect my office PC without running every time in my cellar.

Comment: thx @Max for editing.

Comment: Natively, there's not much you can do. Download [PSTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) and you can use the [PSExec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) command to send remote commands.

Comment: I guess you mean to boot your PC remotely when you talk about "reconnecting"... ever heard about [Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)?

Answer (score 1):

The SHUTDOWN command can remotely turn off other computers on your network but I am not sure what you mean by reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the tools described here ? If you are not on the latest version (or rather server version) of Windows, then you might have to download the tools mentioned here.
http://network-shutdown.com/remotely-shutdown-computers-on-network